# Laravel 5 get select option value

Tags: laravel-5

in my create function, I do

```
$clients = Client::lists('clientName');
return View::make('projects.create', compact('clients'));
```

In my View, I then populate the select by doing this

```
 {!! Form::select('clientName', $clients, Input::old('clients'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

When I view the html, I see something like the following

```
<select name="clientName" id="clientName" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">John Dandy</option>
</select>
```

Now in my store function, I need to get the value John Dandy, not 0.  If I do

```
$clientName = Input::get('clientName');
```

I get 0.  How can I set the value to the clientName or get the option in my store function?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the array returned by `llsts` method to be a key => value pair, if so, what do you want the _key_ to be as the value will be the person's name.

Comment: I dont mind a key value pair.  They can both be clientName.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify only *one* argument for the `lists` method, it will return an array of values automatically mapped to a *counter* key part starting with `0` (that's why you're getting that `0`).

However, using Laravel's Query builder method `lists`, you can specify a custom *key* column as the second parameter ([Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)).

So if you were to get a *key value pair* where the *value* acts as the key itself, you could do the following:

```
$clients = Client::lists('name', 'name');
```

Or, if you wanted an *id* => *client* array:

```
$clients = Client::lists('name', 'id');
```